# Можно ли как то тестировать приложение с использованием ARcore прямо в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, arcore

Вопрос может звучать глупо, но можно ли как то подключить внешнюю камеру и что-бы её можно было вертеть для тестирования приложения. Просто переключатся скидывать всё время на телефон немного неудобно зарание спасибо.

Comment: Возможно, [это](https://makaka.org/unity-tutorials/ar-testing) и [это](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ar-foundation-editor-remote-test-and-debug-your-ar-project-in-the-editor.898433/) - то, что Вы ищете

Comment: А что, если вместо тестирования на телефоне запускать приложения в BlueStacks? (это - приложение, которое на компе эмулирует андроидный телефон) По моему, в нём можно назанчить подключенную камеру в качестве камеры смартфона

Comment: подключи обычную вебку к компьютеру и используй ее как камеру телефона. Если нету вебки - подключи телефон как веб-камеру.